# AV1 codecs string for type attribute of source HTML5 video element

Tags: html, video

It is quite unclear at the moment what exact type attribute value should be defined for codecs string to make AV1 work in Chromium based browsers. 
When I put it like that on top of sources (video files without sound track)

```
type='video/webm; codecs="av1"'
```

Chrome still refuses to play av1 and picks vp9 to playback that is below

```
type='video/webm; codecs="vp9"'
```

Although if I remove codecs string entirely Chrome will play AV1 just fine.

So the question is: What codecs string value should be defined for AV1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the correct type according this [article about using AV1](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/better-web-video-with-av1-codec):

```
<source type="video/webm; codecs=av01.0.05M.08">
```

Comment: Why does MDN give this example? av01.0.15 What is the relevance of all the numbers? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter#av1

Comment: That isn't the correct type for every AV1 video. Here's how to figure out the correct value for a given video https://jakearchibald.com/2022/html-codecs-parameter-for-av1/